# JetBrains CLion can not suggest member methods of string

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm new to JetBrains' CLion. Sorry if my question is basic but I didn't find any answer by searching.

```
#include <string>
int main() {

std::string str;
str.assign("ABC");

}
```

This very simple code compiles fine but the problem is the editor can't suggest member methods for str.

I'm using CLion 2016.3.2 on Fedora 25

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ITP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
include_directories(/usr/include /usr/local/include /usr/local/pgsql/include)
set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.cpp
        commander.cpp
        )

add_custom_target(ITP command make -C /home/ben/projects/ITP)
```

> Note: when I point to #include  the editor didn't knows relevant include file!

Comment: The name of the `typedef` is `std::string`, not `string`.  The compiler won't be able to find it either unless you qualify the name or add a `using` directive.

Comment: that was typing mistake. thanks to you I did the edition. but the problem still remains

Comment: Have you opened clion in power-save mode?

Comment: no, I searched about power-save and find out that my editor is not in power-save mode

Comment: What about reloading the cmake project and compiling? Does it compile at all? You can also try closing clion and opening it again.

Comment: yes as I said It compiles fine and the problem remains after restarting even the machine!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I reached to an answer!

Clion works with Cmake. there for CMakeLists.txt is very important.
many settings with cmake can effect code compilation, build types and ...

for more details please see my new CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(ITP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main.cpp
    commander.cpp)
link_directories(/usr/local/pgsql/lib/)

message("CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
message("C Flags = ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")

add_executable(itp OrderManagementSystem/main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET itp POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.ini
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})



TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( itp
        pthread
        boost_system boost_thread
        protobuf
        zmq
        pq
        )
```

I'm new with both Clion and cmake. but these two ..

Comment: Had the same problem, I fixed it by reloading CMake from Tools > CMake > Reload CMake Project. Then I found an error in the cmake report window in the IDE. For some reason the compiler file I was using was 0 bytes. I replaced the file, reloaded the project and it works.